# How to test Socket.IO Client in Karma's watch mode?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jasmine, karma-runner

I think what I need to do is reset Socket.io entirely after each test using socket.io.

Any ideas? Here's what I'm doing:

I have a test using Socket.IO's Client library, an angular service (github.com/chrisenytc/ng-socket), requireJS, and a local test server. When using karma's watch feature, it runs fine the first time, but fails subsequent attempts (event listeners aren't triggered, debug logging shows an 'xhr poll error').

the simple version of the test is ([full version](https://github.com/loadedsith/ignisLibriColloqui/blob/master/src/app/services/ilcServerService.spec.js)):

```
define(['services/serviceModule', 'angular-mocks'], function() {
  describe('ILC Server Services', function() {

    var socket;

    beforeEach(module('ignisLibriColloqui.services', function(Config, $socketProvider) {
      $socketProvider.setUrl(Config.ilcTestServerUrl);
      Config.ilcServerUrl = Config.ilcTestServerUrl;
      url = Config.ilcTestServerUrl;
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function(ILCServerService, $socket) {
      ilcServerService = ILCServerService;
      socket = $socket;
    }));

    it('expects emit(\'ping\') to trigger on(\'pong\')', function(done) {
      socket.emit('ping',{})
      socket.on('pong',function(data) {
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and the simple server is ([full version](https://github.com/loadedsith/ignisLibriColloqui/blob/master/test/testServer.js))

```
var httpPort = 10999;
var socketPort = 5001;

var restify = require('restify');
var socketio = require('socket.io')(socketPort);
var fs = require('fs');

var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'ilcServer Mock'
});

var io = socketio.listen(server);

server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  'directory': __dirname,
  'default': './app/index.html',
  'maxAge': 0
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var socketId = socket.id;
  console.log('user connected');
  socket.on('ping', function(data) {
    console.log('ping');
    socket.emit('pong', data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});

server.listen(httpPort, function() {
  console.log('restify server listening at %s', server.url, 'socket port:', socketPort);
});
```

**Edit**

After carefully exploring the connections using the [logging described by the Socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/) it has become clear to me that disconnecting the client is not enough. The client logs the "pong" events without firing the `socket.on('pong',event)`, even when using an afterEach to cause `socket.disconnect()` and `socket.io.connect(function(){done()})` to trigger, the new calls to `socket.emit` are not triggered.

Comment: It looks like the socket is being closed in between runs, but that the connection is not being re-established.  Does either a `disconnect` or `reconnect` message come through on either the server or client at any point?  If so, it might be as simple as waiting for the reconnect.  Otherwise, I'm afraid to say that ngSocket does not support re-initializing the connection, which would be the only other way I'm aware of.

Comment: You can start with adding an afterEach where you disconnect your socket. You should probably also do some more cleanup of socket events that you add.

Comment: @kevin.groat Yeah, the client disconnects, Im not sure if this is present in the tests, but I do have a functional disconnect -> reconnect loop in the client, yet the test fails.

Comment: @jornare The socket events are destroyed in the service. Simply disconnecting/reconnecting the client doesn't solve the problem.